# Magento - robots.txt may be blocking URLs on Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: magento, robots.txt, google-search-console

Basically my clients Magento website on Googles Webmaster Tools is showing some really odd results and we've noticed, that on the **Indexed Status** page we have **1,911 pages** indexed. Now this bit seems correct, but when we click the **Advanced** tab it shows we have **6,947** URLs blocked. Now the question I need to ask is, how is there **6,947** URLs blocked, when the website only has around **1,911** pages indexed?

Now I read somewhere that the blocked URLs might be duplicated images that are within Magento. To me this makes sense as we do have a lot of duplicated images in our system, but I'm unsure if this is the cause of the blocked URLs.

Another problem might be down to the robots.txt file itself. So I decided to look into the file and everything looked fine, but each line such as '**Disallow: /404/**' might be pointing in the wrong direction.

The clients website is based within the root of the server, so within the **'public_html'** section of the website and I think the **'/404/'** section might be the root. So would I have to add the website folder name to the beginning of each line within the robots.txt file such as: /[Folder_Name]/404/?

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I've hit a wall. I think the Magento version is 1.5 if that could help.

Thanks for the help again.

ROBOTS.TXT FILE CODE

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /
Sitemap: http://www.websitename/sitemap.xml

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/
# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt
# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /*?p=*&
Disallow: /*?SID=
Disallow: /*?invis=
Disallow: /*?tag=
Disallow: /*?osCsid=
Disallow: /*?manufacturers_id=
Disallow: /*?currency=
```

Comment: Might have more luck on the http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: After logging into webmaster tools, go to blocked urls section under crawl, there you can find exactly which line in your robots.txt is causing what to your site.

Comment: You should really go through your robots.txt, it's having a lot of rules that are not even needed.

Comment: Umm... `Disallow: /catalog/category/view/ Disallow: /catalog/product/view/` probably leaves the site unspiderable.

Answer (score 1):

How your server handles folders doesn’t matter.

If your robots.txt is accessible from `http://example.com/robots.txt`, a rule like `Disallow: /404/` will block

- `http://example.com/404/`
- `http://example.com/404/foo`
- `http://example.com/404/foo/bar`
- etc.

---

Also note that you must not have line breaks in a record, so this

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /
Sitemap: http://www.websitename/sitemap.xml

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
```

should be:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://www.websitename/sitemap.xml
# Directories
Disallow: /404/
```

---

And it seems that you don’t need `Allow: /` (it’s not part of the original robots.txt specification, but even for parsers that understand `Allow`, it’s the default that anything is allowed which is not disallowed).

---

> Now the question I need to ask is, how is there 6,947 URLs blocked, when the website only has around 1,911 pages indexed?

I can’t follow you here. While Google may still index but not crawl blocked URLs, it’s not the case that this happens for all blocked URLs. So the number of indexed URLs wouldn’t typically include all blocked URLs. As Google is not allowed to visit/crawl blockd URLs, it can’t possibly know if or how many of those URLs exist. Google learns about them when finding links to these URLs (from within your site as well as from external sites).

So if there were 100 links to different URLs whose paths start with `/poll/`, Google might list these 100 URLs as blocked.

Comment: Do you think the blocked URLs could be caused by something in the robots.txt file? I'm not to using the robots file within Magento and there's certain pages that need blocking etc.

Comment: @LeeEaseman: Each `Disallow` rule line can cause this; that’s the whole point of using `Disallow`, isn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your sitemap is conflicting with the robots.txt file.

Google tries to index everything that is in the sitemap.xml file, but it sees that it cannot index the pages that are blocked by the robots.txt file.

In my case [www.workwearwebshop.nl](https://www.workwearwebshop.nl), the sitemap contained pages starting with /catalog/product/view that were blocked by robots.txt.
If you comment out that line in robots.txt Google can spider these products.
Problem that remains is that magento should have better url's than these (starting with the category name instead of /catalog/product/view)